# Python, keep only sentence from html and remove all non-alphabet, number

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I got html from the website and change it to txt.

However, how to clean the txt so that i keep only the sentences in the txt.

for example: I want to remove all irrelevent information such as 1990...himself,1987, the 59th ....

keep the sentences:

tom cruise is an american actor who has starred in many blockbuster movies and as of 2012 is the highest paid actor in hollywood. he is also a film producer and owns a production company. tom cruise has been the winner of three golden globe awards and has been nominated thrice for academy awards. apart from this, many of the movies cruise has starred in have been huge blockbusters on the box office.
after repeated success in many films, tom cruise kept going on with release of two mission impossible movies, war of the worlds which was a super duper box office hit and many more.

and so on.

```
1990
... himself
1987
the 59th annual academy awards
(tv special)
jack
/
maverick
/
vincent lauria
(uncredited)
related videos
none
none
none
see all 35 videos  »
@csm.csm_widget />
reality tv
the office
late night
sitcoms
music
rappers
action
religion
top paid
how much money does tom cruise make? (salary & net worth)
tom cruise is an american actor who has starred in many blockbuster movies and as of 2012 is the highest paid actor in hollywood. he is also a film producer and owns a production company. tom cruise has been the winner of three golden globe awards and has been nominated thrice for academy awards. apart from this, many of the movies cruise has starred in have been huge blockbusters on the box office.
history
thomas cruise mapother iv a.k.a tom cruise was born in syracuse, new york to mother mary lee and father thomas cruise mapother iii. cruise’s mother was a special education teacher and father was an electrical engineer. tom cruise is basically of irish, german and english origin. cruise’s family had the male domination of his abusive father whom cruise had once described as the merchant of chaos. he was often bullied and beaten by his father and cruise called him a coward. a part of tom cruise’s childhood was spent in canada. however, when cruise was in the sixth grade, his mother left his father and brought cruise and his siblings back to america.
acting career
acting career of tom cruise started quite early but with a small role in the movie endless love (1981). however, he got his big break as a supporting actor in the movie taps later that year. in 1983, his movies risky business and all the right moves along with top gun in 1986 paved the path for tom cruise as an established actor and a superstar. after this there was no looking back and tom cruise went to star in many super-successful movies like cocktail, rain man, days of thunder, interview with the vampire.
then in 1996, he starred as a superspy ethan hunt in the very popular and blockbuster movie which went on to be a series, mission: impossible. that same year he also was seen in the lead role of the movie jerry maguire and won a golden globe for the same. in 1999, his supporting role in the movie magnolia again won him his second golden globe.
after repeated success in many films, tom cruise kept going on with release of two mission impossible movies, war of the worlds which was a super duper box office hit and many more.
net worth
tom cruise’s films have gained $7.3 million worldwide as of 2013. however, the net worth of the highest paid actor in hollywood is $270 million and he still gets paychecks from his previous movies.
154 magazine cover photos
|
none »
official sites:
facebook
|
official site
|
none
»
alternate names:
tomu kurûzu
height:
5' 7" (1.7 m)
none
did you know?
personal quote:
(1992 quote) i really enjoy talking to other actors and directors. sometimes, if i see their movies, i'll call them up or write them a note saying, "i enjoyed it," or asking, "how did you do that? how did you make that work?". i just saw
```

html text is called: text

```
    sentence = re.sub(' ', '\n', text)
    sentence = re.sub('none', '', words)

    print sentence
```

the result:  the sentence is destroyed.

```
ethan
hunt
/
ray
ferrier
(uncredited)
2006
the
late
late
show
with
craig
ferguson
(tv
series)
himself
-
episode
#2.140
(2006)
...
himself
(uncredited)
2006
getaway
(tv
series)
himself
-
seven
wonders
of
the
world
(2006)
...
himself
2006
cmt
insider
(tv
series)
himself
-
episode
dated
29
april
2006
(2006)
...
himself
2005-2006
corazón
de...
(tv
series)
himself
-
episode
dated
19
january
2006
(2006)
...
himself
-
episode
dated
15
november
2005
(2005)
...
himself
-
```

Comment: Look at Python regex. Be aware that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. You need to do the hard work, and come back when you have a specific issue.

Comment: i used regex, but it separate the sentence into individual words

Comment: @HiPownedBi - then that would have been good information to include. What code did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: @AndrewGuy  i updated the question

Comment: @Klaus i updated the question

Comment: So you want code that recognises the difference between a full sentence and a sentence fragment? How do you define a sentence? What about questions?

Comment: the proper english sentence. the sentence can also incluse questions. as i need the sentences to do NLTK analysis. So it must have the punctuatuins!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(\s*?\S*){5}$
```

The code is currently set to select any line that has five words or less. You can increase/decrease the number of words by changing the value of `{5}`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/z2qxrx/3